# iOS embed video, video still plays when in another view

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, embed, uicollectionview

So lets say I have a UIWebView on my view, embed with a YouTube video. The view is connected to a navigation view controller. This means that when i click a button it pushes a view on to the stack. But when I play the youtube video and go to the next view. The video is still playing. Is there anyway to handle stopping an embed youtube video when going to another view?

What if I have multiple cells with a UIWebView embed with a YouTube video in a UICollectionView? I don't have reference to all the UIWebViews to set to nil. (Sorry for the confusion previously above)

Answer (score 1):

What I do is just set the UIWebView's content to nil when I'm moving to another page, which removes the video player completely, but if you just want to pause the video so the user can resume when they come back, you'll have to talk to the youtube player using javascript. See [How to Pause Media Playback in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640135/how-to-pause-media-playback-in-uiwebview) for one approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Youtube Javascript api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=us) to play the video - you can pause it when leaving current view with

```
-(void)viewWillDisapper:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"player.pauseVideo();"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load a blank page into the UIWebView to stop the video playing. Here's a quick way to do it:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated]
    [yourWebView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];        
}
```

Comment: I probably should have made my question more clearer. What if I have embed youTube videos in like a UICollectionView? Then i don't have reference to each cell that has a UIWebView :X